# Can't assign evaled value to the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, type-conversion, eval

I have to change string to list that contains dicts. When I try to make `eval` function on one discrite value in my dataframe, the value perfectly converts. Problem is when when I want to make it on each row in the loop.

In:

```py
df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'][234]
```

Out:

```py
"[{'X': -114.3, 'Y': -114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}, {'X': 114.3, 'Y': -114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}, {'X': -114.3, 'Y': 114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}, {'X': 114.3, 'Y': 114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}]"
```

In:

```py
list(eval(df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'][234]))
```

Out:

```py
[{'X': -114.3, 'Y': -114.3, 'IsSlotted': False},
 {'X': 114.3, 'Y': -114.3, 'IsSlotted': False},
 {'X': -114.3, 'Y': 114.3, 'IsSlotted': False},
 {'X': 114.3, 'Y': 114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}]
```

In:

```py
for x in range(df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'].shape[0]):
    string = df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'][x]
    df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'][x] = list(eval(string))
```

In:

```py
df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'][234]
```

Out:

```py
"[{'X': -114.3, 'Y': -114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}, {'X': 114.3, 'Y': -114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}, {'X': -114.3, 'Y': 114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}, {'X': 114.3, 'Y': 114.3, 'IsSlotted': False}]"
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: `df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'][x] = ...` should be giving a `SettingWithCopyWarning` no? [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20625582/15497888) note the answer outlines that setting on a copy will not reflect in the DataFrame.

Comment: Yes, it is. How to obey it?

Comment: Something like `df_clean.loc[x, 'CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'] = list(eval(string))`. But something like `df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'] = df_clean['CalculatedData.AnchorLayoutPoints'].apply(eval)` instead of the loop might be better overall.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Second option works perfectly.